# How to get the total value using Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get data from Google Analytics using API with apps script.
I already secceed to get values of each metrics by each dimension but total values are not shown.
On the web view, I can see the total values of each metrics at top of the table.  Is there any way to get this through API?

Here is the code to make the request.

```
function ChannelReportPC(firstProfile) { //

  var profileId = firstProfile.getId();
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;
  var startDate = electiveStartDate();   
  var endDate = electiveEndDate();      

  var optArgs = { 
    'dimensions': 'ga:medium',              // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    'sort': '-ga:sessions',       // Sort by sessions descending, then keyword.
    'segment': 'sessions::condition::ga:deviceCategory==desktop,ga:deviceCategory==tablet',  // Process desktop or tablet traffic.
    'start-index': '1',
    'max-results': '20'                     // Display the first 250 results.
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
      tableId,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
    'ga:sessions,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:transactionsPerSession', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
     optArgs
     );

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();

  if (results.getRows()) {
    return results;

  } else {
    throw new Error('No views (profiles) found');
  }
}
```

Here is the code to output the result on sheet.

```
function outputToSpreadsheet(results) {　

  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  // Print the headers.
  var headerNames = [];
  for (var i = 0, header; header = results.getColumnHeaders()[i]; ++i) {
    headerNames.push(header.getName());
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, headerNames.length)
      .setValues([headerNames])
      .setBackground('#eeeeee');


  // Print the rows of data.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.getRows().length, headerNames.length)
      .setValues(results.getRows());

  var output = [];
  var totals = results.totalsForAllResults;
  for (metricName in totals) {
    output.push(
        'Metric Name  = ', metricName, '\n',
        'Metric Total = ', totals[metricName], '\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this with AppScripts but there should be something called totalsForAllResults.  It totals each of the metric columns. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#response_fields

Comment: @DaImTo is correct, if you post the actual code you're using to make the request, I can help you find the totals values in the response.

Comment: Thanks, I added my code. I'll be glad if you show me how to use the   "totalsForAllResults".